# Apps crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when changing to a custom keyboard layout

Tags: macos, crash, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I have a custom layout installed ([svdvorak_mac6.keylayout](http://tlundqvist.org/sv_dvorak/drivers/)). After a reboot another keyboard layout was selected, so I selected my usual one instead. This lead to a lot of apps suddenly starting to crash (Chrome, Skype, Adium etc).

I can change to any other built in layout for OS X, but as soon as I choose one custom installed one (either form ~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/ or from /Library/Keyboard Layouts/) the apps crash. The only thing I can remember that I did before the reboot was to install [Google's video chat plugin](http://www.google.com/chat/video) for the browser.

Here's the crash report from Adium:

```
Process:         Adium [372]
Path:            /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/MacOS/Adium
Identifier:      com.adiumX.adiumX
Version:         1.4.1 (1.4.1)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [182]

Date/Time:       2010-12-22 22:39:47.833 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.5 (10H574)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          257401 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           39
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1178959 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   8
Anonymous UUID:                      7CBACDEB-FBAF-4CD5-9C15-7AEA8AC4B5EF

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x99722b6d islGetInputSourceProperty + 1107
1   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x9972262c TSMGetInputSourceProperty + 526
2   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x9972787a _ISSendWindowServerKeyboardLayoutUpdate + 412
3   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x9972622b _TSMSetInputSourceSelected + 1429
4   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x99980209 TSMMessagePortCallBack + 574
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9226840c __CFMessagePortPerform + 540
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d34db __CFRunLoopRun + 6523
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d1464 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d1291 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
9   com.apple.HIToolbox            0x99717f58 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
10  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x99717d0f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 354
11  com.apple.HIToolbox            0x99717b94 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 81
12  com.apple.AppKit               0x9189478d _DPSNextEvent + 847
13  com.apple.AppKit               0x91893fce -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 156
14  com.apple.AppKit               0x91856247 -[NSApplication run] + 821
15  com.apple.AppKit               0x9184e2d9 NSApplicationMain + 574
16  com.adiumX.adiumX              0x0000322e 0x1000 + 8750

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f5982 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f609c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f5559 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f52fe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4d81 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4bc6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4a12 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4fa8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4bc6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968ee0c6 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x92211c83 __CFSocketManager + 1091
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc85d _pthread_start + 345
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4a12 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4fa8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968f4bc6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968cf15a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fcce5 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x9692bac8 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   ...apple.AddressBook.framework 0x9310043f -[ABRemoteImageLoader workLoop] + 283
4   com.apple.Foundation           0x97822bf0 -[NSThread main] + 45
5   com.apple.Foundation           0x97822ba0 __NSThread__main__ + 1499
6   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc85d _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968cf0fa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968cf867 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d237f __CFRunLoopRun + 2079
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d1464 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x921d1291 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
5   com.apple.Foundation           0x9785b7d0 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 329
6   com.apple.Foundation           0x97822bf0 -[NSThread main] + 45
7   com.apple.Foundation           0x97822ba0 __NSThread__main__ + 1499
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc85d _pthread_start + 345
9   libSystem.B.dylib              0x968fc6e2 thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000670  ebx: 0x9972272e  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000002
  edi: 0xa0c3b214  esi: 0x00000004  ebp: 0xbfffe6c8  esp: 0xbfffe660
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x99722b6d   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x1a0ff7 +com.adiumX.adiumX 1.4.1 (1.4.1) <136586E8-F3F5-99ED-DB1F-48C0027686CB> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/MacOS/Adium
  0x1f9000 -   0x23efe7 +AIUtilities ??? (???) <565A1BC2-4B50-6277-D127-AFBF01F90CE3> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/AIUtilities.framework/Versions/A/AIUtilities
  0x2af000 -   0x307ff7 +com.adiumX.AdiumPurple ??? (1.0) <F4C2A8E4-695E-7CCE-41F3-F8960AFDC149> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/AdiumLibpurple.framework/Versions/A/AdiumLibpurple
  0x34b000 -   0x3ddfe7 +Adium ??? (???) <774A171B-ED45-D221-6A37-486AA15C8BA5> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Adium.framework/Versions/A/Adium
  0x439000 -   0x510ff7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libglib 2.0.0 (2.0.0) <C620AA58-CFC4-855E-1F2F-F84D9335CD5D> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libglib.framework/Versions/2.0.0/libglib
  0x53d000 -   0x53eff7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libgmodule 2.0.0 (2.0.0) <11FF9396-454A-394B-1B12-D84AD535F6F6> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgmodule.framework/Versions/2.0.0/libgmodule
  0x542000 -   0x578fe7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libgobject 2.0.0 (2.0.0) <D69FB8D0-D271-EC20-42DD-04FCC65A72BF> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgobject.framework/Versions/2.0.0/libgobject
  0x58e000 -   0x590ff7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libgthread 2.0.0 (2.0.0) <5D4B8DC6-28E3-9285-8E2A-2D7A3CBE11C5> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgthread.framework/Versions/2.0.0/libgthread
  0x594000 -   0x59eff7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libintl 8 (8) <343C9F94-8840-4465-64E4-86A0092AD69F> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libintl.framework/Versions/8/libintl
  0x5a3000 -   0x5cbff7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libmeanwhile 1 (1) <7B341D44-FA86-F7C3-E800-7D1169EB9CE2> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmeanwhile.framework/Versions/1/libmeanwhile
  0x5e0000 -   0x81bff7 +libpurple 8.5.0 (compatibility 8.0.0) <DEB5CE6C-2A4A-16CA-E0EF-DDE812865406> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpurple.framework/Versions/0/libpurple
  0x8c3000 -   0x978fe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib 0.9.7 (compatibility 0.9.7) <AACC86C0-86B4-B1A7-003F-2A0AF68973A2> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
  0x9be000 -   0x9ccff7 +com.dpompa.fribidi ??? (1.0) <EA8AEBCF-DFE5-85FB-5C0E-EB3AB5B0A950> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/FriBidi.framework/Versions/A/FriBidi
 0x21d2000 -  0x21e1fe7 +AutoHyperlinks ??? (???) <A8B5F9E1-E259-F33F-9E60-F4E37B1ED500> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/AutoHyperlinks.framework/Versions/A/AutoHyperlinks
 0x21e7000 -  0x21f3ff7 +net.brockerhoff.RBSplitView.Framework 1.1.4 (1.1.4) <D92691AA-294F-A85D-E7E1-01AD0A0717D2> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/RBSplitView.framework/Versions/A/RBSplitView
 0x21fb000 -  0x220efff +org.andymatuschak.Sparkle 1.5 Beta (bzr) (340) <E0109DBE-F614-66D0-9B82-6151BC40DAD7> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
 0x221c000 -  0x226cfef +com.adiumX.OTR ??? (1.0) <BAE9D6BD-60D5-B53B-19BC-C17287F55EE9> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/OTR.framework/Versions/A/OTR
 0x227d000 -  0x2280ff7 +org.boredzo.LMX ??? (1.0) <92632179-5CFB-EA6B-AAE7-5F4B98BF0CD9> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/LMX.framework/Versions/A/LMX
 0x2286000 -  0x228dff1 +net.oauth.OAuthConsumer ??? (0.1.1) <025882EC-04DA-763B-18F5-5266A5D185FD> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/OAuthConsumer.framework/Versions/A/OAuthConsumer
 0x2296000 -  0x22a6fe7 +com.googlepages.openspecies.rtool.libjson-glib 1.0.0 (1.0.0) <016CAFB1-DD85-3C9D-411C-C696D9D57213> /Applications/Adium.app/Contents/Frameworks/libjson-glib.framework/Versions/1.0.0/libjson-glib
 0x2784000 -  0x2788ff3  com.apple.audio.AudioIPCPlugIn 1.1.6 (1.1.6) <F402CF88-D96C-42A0-3207-49759F496AE8> /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn
 0x278d000 -  0x2793ffb  com.apple.audio.AppleHDAHALPlugIn 1.9.9 (1.9.9f12) <82BFF5E9-2B0E-FE8B-8370-445DD94DA434> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn
0x15fda000 - 0x15fdcff7  apop.so ??? (???) <B365DF5B-6A00-9595-27FF-4811B12B1C19> /usr/lib/sasl2/apop.so
0x15fe0000 - 0x15fe9ff7  digestmd5WebDAV.so ??? (???) <FC8C0A3E-1BC3-5016-95E1-E7EF9FF37242> /usr/lib/sasl2/digestmd5WebDAV.so
0x15fee000 - 0x15ff0ff7  libanonymous.2.so ??? (???) <41A1E196-0AB4-1ADD-6362-BB53A0E57ABA> /usr/lib/sasl2/libanonymous.2.so
0x15ff4000 - 0x15ff6ff7  libcrammd5.2.so ??? (???) <032F08C3-2D26-F956-4799-1012A1BBCB71> /usr/lib/sasl2/libcrammd5.2.so
0x15ffa000 - 0x15ffcff7  login.so ??? (???) <4E0B45F7-243E-A3FD-AA75-EF653590BF17> /usr/lib/sasl2/login.so
0x16100000 - 0x16116ff7  dhx.so ??? (???) <B50D8278-4246-4086-E0AF-3CBE96AE9837> /usr/lib/sasl2/dhx.so
0x16123000 - 0x1612bff7  libdigestmd5.2.so ??? (???) <E8D78B02-D51C-F2CB-C4BA-AC9231ED8006> /usr/lib/sasl2/libdigestmd5.2.so
0x16130000 - 0x16135ff7  libgssapiv2.2.so ??? (???) <193995B9-1C15-BEB2-40B7-1598D82F29BB> /usr/lib/sasl2/libgssapiv2.2.so
0x1613a000 - 0x1613fff7  libntlm.so ??? (???) <F97C955D-E521-216F-E8F0-79E8C907217A> /usr/lib/sasl2/libntlm.so
0x16144000 - 0x1614bff7  libotp.2.so ??? (???) <3DF61F7F-4929-A37D-01CB-9A7A90E3B9B7> /usr/lib/sasl2/libotp.2.so
0x16152000 - 0x16154ff7  libplain.2.so ??? (???) <5CC9D89A-9656-EEE8-64AB-E61A22FA8465> /usr/lib/sasl2/libplain.2.so
0x16158000 - 0x1615cff7  libpps.so ??? (???) <C5A25A99-412E-AD7F-D6FD-C4CC07B7B2A5> /usr/lib/sasl2/libpps.so
0x16161000 - 0x16164ff7  mschapv2.so ??? (???) <34DFB657-5E2E-5B83-713B-F57ACFB1E091> /usr/lib/sasl2/mschapv2.so
0x16169000 - 0x1616bff7  shadow_auxprop.so ??? (???) <4073854F-B4C8-A0D4-C0FF-7A0C93BFC70E> /usr/lib/sasl2/shadow_auxprop.so
0x16170000 - 0x16172ff7  smb_lm.so ??? (???) <4B7A54D8-241D-CC8C-8759-4C7DC562369D> /usr/lib/sasl2/smb_lm.so
0x16177000 - 0x1617aff7  smb_nt.so ??? (???) <7B7D31B1-10A1-1AE9-E323-C19A3C52DC03> /usr/lib/sasl2/smb_nt.so
0x1617f000 - 0x16182ff7  smb_ntlmv2.so ??? (???) <3BFE5AA9-F215-36B5-E7D7-46BE1BFD63EA> /usr/lib/sasl2/smb_ntlmv2.so
0x194c1000 - 0x19639fe7  GLEngine ??? (???) <A4BBE58C-1211-0473-7B78-C3BA7AC29C9B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x1966b000 - 0x19a70fe7  libclh.dylib 3.1.1 C  (3.1.1) <D1A3D8AD-0FED-4AD2-AB43-CF804B7BDBF9> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libclh.dylib
0x19ae8000 - 0x19b0cfe7  GLRendererFloat ??? (???) <EFE5EC6D-74B2-37A2-92E4-526A2EF6B791> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
0x8f0c8000 - 0x8f811ff7  com.apple.GeForceGLDriver 1.6.24 (6.2.4) <DCC16E52-B1F1-90E6-E839-D30DF4CBA468> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???) <39AC3185-E633-68AA-7CD6-1230E7F1CEF4> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x90005fe7  com.apple.ExceptionHandling 1.5 (10) <03218275-EBEC-39AA-895A-BA72A5FDBB7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExceptionHandling.framework/Versions/A/ExceptionHandling
0x90006000 - 0x90074ff7  com.apple.QuickLookUIFramework 2.3 (327.6) <74706A08-5399-24FE-00B2-4A702A6B83C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/QuickLookUI
0x90075000 - 0x900b2ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.5 (1.10.2) <362DF639-6E5F-9371-9B99-81C581A8EE41> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x900fa000 - 0x901d5feb  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.9 (1.5.9) <CED00AC1-924B-0E45-7D5E-1CEA8929F5BE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x901d6000 - 0x9021aff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <2234855E-3BED-717F-0BFA-D1A289ECDBDA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x9021b000 - 0x9021bff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x90258000 - 0x90302fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.11.5 (454.11.5) <D8963574-285A-3BD6-6B25-07D39C6F67A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x90303000 - 0x9033efeb  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <4FB144ED-8AF9-27CF-B315-DCE5575D5231> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x90342000 - 0x90366ff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <46AF3A0F-2B8D-87B9-62D4-0905678A64DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x90367000 - 0x9036afe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x9036b000 - 0x903d5fe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x903d6000 - 0x903daff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <D849E1A5-6B0C-2A05-2765-850EC39BA2FF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x903db000 - 0x903edff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.10 (207.10) <E1A6F663-570B-CE54-0F8A-BBCCDECE3B42> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x90437000 - 0x90470ff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <D6F24434-8217-DF72-2126-1953080680D7> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x9049b000 - 0x904ccff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <78F59EAB-BBD4-7366-CA84-970547501978> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x904ec000 - 0x909a5ffb  com.apple.VideoToolbox 0.484.20 (484.20) <E7B9F015-2569-43D7-5268-375ED937ECA5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Versions/A/VideoToolbox
0x909a6000 - 0x90ab5fe7  com.apple.WebKit 6533.19 (6533.19.4) <A942073C-83DF-33ED-3D01-A24DE8AEAB3D> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit
0x90ab6000 - 0x90ae6ff7  com.apple.MeshKit 1.1 (49.2) <5A74D1A4-4B97-FE39-4F4D-E0B80F0ADD87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MeshKit.framework/Versions/A/MeshKit
0x90cc5000 - 0x90cfdff7  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1) <131ED804-DD88-D84F-13F8-D48E0012B96F> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x90cfe000 - 0x90f61fef  com.apple.security 6.1.1 (37594) <1949216A-7583-B73A-6112-4D55CA5852E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x90f62000 - 0x90f64ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <E7D83480-77BB-72F9-72F3-AEE198CE589F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
0x90f65000 - 0x910e7fe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <35DB7644-0780-D2AB-F6A9-45F28D2D434A> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x910e8000 - 0x91217fe3  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <0A0F68E5-4806-DB51-764B-D97554B801AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x91218000 - 0x91538ff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.23 (861.23) <B08756E4-32C5-CC33-0268-7C00A5ED7537> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x91539000 - 0x91578ff7  com.apple.ImageCaptureCore 1.0.3 (1.0.3) <7E02D104-F31C-CF72-71B4-DA5DF7B48337> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageCaptureCore.framework/Versions/A/ImageCaptureCore
0x91579000 - 0x915b0fe7  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <7DCB5938-3140-E71A-92BD-8C242F30C8F5> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
0x915c4000 - 0x9163ffff  com.apple.AppleVAFramework 4.10.12 (4.10.12) <89C4EBE2-FE27-3160-0BD1-D0C2ED5F3605> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVA
0x91640000 - 0x91742fef  com.apple.MeshKitIO 1.1 (49.2) <D0401AC5-1F92-2BBB-EBAB-58EDD3BA61B9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MeshKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MeshKitIO.framework/Versions/A/MeshKitIO
0x91743000 - 0x91744ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <BE4C2495-B758-AD22-DCC0-56A6791E948E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x91769000 - 0x91777fe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x91778000 - 0x9179afef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.9) <F2EEE9D7-D4FB-14F3-E647-ABD32754F557> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x9184c000 - 0x9212cff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.7 (1038.35) <ABC7783C-E4D5-B848-BED6-99451D94D120> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x9212d000 - 0x9218efe7  com.apple.CoreText 3.5.0 (???) <BB50C045-25F5-65B8-B1DB-8CDAEF45EB46> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x9218f000 - 0x92194ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <C1B46982-7D3B-3CC4-3BC2-3E4B595F0231> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x92195000 - 0x92310fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.4 (550.42) <C78D5079-663E-9734-7AFA-6CE79A0539F1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x92311000 - 0x92351ff3  com.apple.securityinterface 4.0.1 (37214) <43CE8A8D-64E5-F36E-4900-FBB1BD6557F1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
0x92352000 - 0x92355ff7  libCGXType.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <B624AACE-991B-0FFA-2482-E69970576CE1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x924b9000 - 0x925fcfef  com.apple.QTKit 7.6.6 (1756) <4D809734-4E1B-8E18-C825-86C5422FC3DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit
0x925fd000 - 0x9260dff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E276514D-394B-2FDD-6264-07A444AA6A4E> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x92615000 - 0x92618ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <1F738E81-BB71-32C5-F1E9-C1302F71021C> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x9262c000 - 0x92652ffb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x9294d000 - 0x9295dff7  com.apple.DSObjCWrappers.Framework 10.6 (134) <95DC4010-ECC4-3A75-5DEE-11BB2AE895EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSObjCWrappers.framework/Versions/A/DSObjCWrappers
0x9295e000 - 0x929a0ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8A4721DE-25C4-C8AA-EA90-9DA7812E3EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x929a1000 - 0x929abfe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3) <DE0E0EF6-8190-3F65-6BDD-5AC9D8A025D6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x929ac000 - 0x92a5cff3  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.3 (4.6.3) <0354B408-665F-8B3F-87FF-64E6322276F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x92a5d000 - 0x92c3ffff  com.apple.imageKit 2.0.3 (1.0) <B4DB05F7-01C5-35EE-7AB9-41BD9D63F075> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageKit.framework/Versions/A/ImageKit
0x92cf5000 - 0x92d4bff7  com.apple.MeshKitRuntime 1.1 (49.2) <CB9F38B1-E107-EA62-EDFF-02EE79F6D1A5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MeshKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/MeshKitRuntime.framework/Versions/A/MeshKitRuntime
0x92d4c000 - 0x92d55ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <6AA6DDF6-AFC3-BBDB-751A-64AE3580A49E> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x92dc6000 - 0x92df8fe3  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib ??? (???) <6E9D1A50-330E-F1F4-F93D-9ECC8A61B21A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
0x92e7a000 - 0x92e88ff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.11 (1.6.11) <286D1BC4-4CD8-3CD4-F723-5C196FE15FE0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x92e89000 - 0x92ec7ff7  com.apple.QuickLookFramework 2.3 (327.6) <66955C29-0C99-D02C-DB18-4952AFB4E886> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/QuickLook
0x92ec8000 - 0x92f92fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 357 (357) <3A26F553-722D-3536-EEDE-FB41FCDAA7FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x92f93000 - 0x92f97ff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <DA5758A4-71B0-DD6E-7402-B7FB15387569> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x92f98000 - 0x93099fe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <ED8E45C6-B078-15E8-938D-99D8FD1EAE64> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x9309a000 - 0x932a1feb  com.apple.AddressBook.framework 5.0.3 (875) <759B660B-00F6-F08C-37CD-69468C774B5E> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
0x932a2000 - 0x933aeff7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <8B308FAE-843F-EE76-0254-3374CBFFA7B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x933bf000 - 0x933c2ffb  com.apple.help 1.3.1 (41) <6A5AD406-9D8E-5BAC-51E1-E09AB9A6D159> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x933c3000 - 0x9372eff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.34) <CC1C1631-D8D1-D416-171E-A1683274E479> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x9372f000 - 0x93740ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <3036AD83-4F1D-1028-54EE-54165E562650> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x93741000 - 0x93755ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <9F5CE4F7-D05C-8C14-4B76-E43D07A8A680> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x93790000 - 0x937e1ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.1 (???) <51BDD848-32A5-2425-BE07-BD037A89630A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x937e2000 - 0x937e2ff7  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <FCC37057-CDD7-2AF1-21AF-52A06C4048FF> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x937e3000 - 0x93a0eff3  com.apple.QuartzComposer 4.2 ({156.28}) <08AF01DC-110D-9443-3916-699DBDED0149> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzComposer.framework/Versions/A/QuartzComposer
0x93a17000 - 0x93a21ffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <7486003F-8FDB-BD6C-CB34-DE45315BD82C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x93a22000 - 0x93a28fff  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <CE92759E-865E-8A3B-1488-ECD497E4074D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
0x93b47000 - 0x93b94feb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.0 (6.0) <27F3FF53-F818-9836-2101-3E963FE0C0E0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x93b95000 - 0x93c30ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 4.4 (???) <ECB16606-4DF8-4AFB-C91D-F7947C26040F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x93c31000 - 0x93c31ff7  com.apple.quartzframework 1.5 (1.5) <7DD4EBF1-60C4-9329-08EF-6E59731D9430> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Quartz
0x93d51000 - 0x93d72fe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3 (12.3) <DEA600BF-4F54-66B5-DB2F-DC57FD518543> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x93d73000 - 0x93e77fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <BDEFA030-5E75-7C47-2904-85AB16937F45> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib

snip... Superuser character limit :-(
```

**Edit 1:** Also, when changing keyboard layout using the system tray icon, my custom layout is dimmed whenever it is an "official" OS X application (Terminal, Finder etc). It's not dimmed for other applications such as Chrome, Skype etc but then they crash when it is switched instead.

**Edit 2:** Tried with a new administrator account, same problem. The problem is reproducible all the time when changing layout to the custom one (crash for a normal application, dimmed layout option for an "OS X application").

**Edit 3**: I opened the keyboard layout in [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and it said "This keyboard layout is missing output for some special keys. Do you want to add the missing output? This will include the F-keys, and other non-output keys. Yes/No?". I did this and then saved it as a new file (changed the name slightly and gave it a new Keyboard ID. After this, it worked until I did another reboot, then the layout was "corrupted" again.

**Edit 4**: Been using it for a while now and it only works when placed in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`, never in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. Seems that there is a bug in OS X for this kind of layout that allows it to work for a user, but not for the system. The downside of using it as a user is that it is not possible to enable it for system password dialogs (which are run as an administrator).

Comment: It works fine on my machine (though I don't want to restart), both the downloaded file, and copy&pasting the XML into a new file (in which case umlauts are broken, but it doesn't crash). What happens when you disable and remove the layout, then add and activate it again? Does it work until you restart? Did you download the `.keylayout` file, or copy the XML yourself?

Comment: I used "Save Link As..." in Google Chrome. I did try to remove it and add it again, change the name and so on. I guess it was the content that was broken somehow. Strange that it worked for over a month before crashing. Maybe something changed in OS X in an update or so?

Answer (score 0):

I did a diff on the file I saved from Ukulele against the file that now was in /Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/ and the keys that Ukulele complained about earlier was missing again. It is possible that somehow I was running a cached copy of my new layout when I thought "it worked" and that it re-read it from the system folder after the reboot.

I have now copied my fixed layout to my home folder instead, ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/. This seems to survive a restart.

**Edit**: *This doesn't allow me to use the layout in system password dialogs though, so it is not a complete solution.*

Answer (score 0):

The following command removes the keyloard layout caches, and fixed the problem for me (on OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard, with custom keyboard layout installed in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`):

```
sudo rm -f /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le*
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) would be even better if you edit it to provide some explanation as to *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.